# Functional equation that models trigonometric identities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, functional-equations

Find, with proof, all continuous functions $f,g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)^2 + g(x)^2 = 1$ and $2f(x)g(x)=f(2x)$. I am aware that the solution pair $(f,g)=(\sin{ax},\cos{ax})$ satisfies the conditions, but cannot determine what other solutions exist.

Comment: Do the functions need to be continuous? If not, there are horrendously pathological solutions that can't even be described in a finite amount of space.

Comment: Yes. Assume that the functions are continuous.

Comment: For *any* (continuous) function $h(x)$, the pair $(f,g) = (\sin h(x),\cos h(x))$ satisfy the two conditions. So there are many more solutions; I don't know if these are the only ones. The two conditions together (after adding/subtracting) imply that $|f|\le1$, which might help in showing that these are the only solutions.

Comment: I fail to see why $\sin 2h(x)=\sin h(2x)$ as seemingly required for the second condition to be true for $(\sin h(x), \cos h(x))$ with arbitrary $h$, given that $2\sin h(x)\cos h(x)=\sin 2h(x)$.  Naively it would seem that we must have $2h(x)=h(2x)+2k_x\pi$ for all $x$ and some $k_x\in\mathbb{Z}$.  Also, the first condition alone implies $|f|\le 1$ given that $f$ and $g$ take only real values.